# Proposing "variant" tag

Tags: feature-request, tags

I propose a tag [variant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variant) which I think is important, but this is a special tag which cannot stand alone. This tag means the variant of another tag.

If we create a puzzle like solving a modified horse step on chessboard, I think it **quite misleading** if we put the tag [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), but it is not if we put 2 tags [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess) and [variant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variant).

I checked the tags, and there are many that can be put together with the proposed [variant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variant) tag. For example, [chess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chess), [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku), [rubiks-cube](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rubiks-cube), [dice](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dice), [matches](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/matches), [dominoes](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dominoes), [tic-tac-toe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tic-tac-toe), [scrabble](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scrabble), etc.

I have created a [sudoku-like puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/41673/hexagon-sudoku-like-puzzle), and I put the tag [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku). But my friend says it is not sudoku, so I should not put the tag [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku).

Comment: I don't think it's a *necessary* tag because if there is a significant variance, it'll be explained in the puzzle. Nonetheless, it would be nice to have.

Answer (score 4):

Smells like a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) to me, and therefore wouldn't make a good tag... It makes no sense on it's own and it arguably means different things to different people (or depending on what other tags are present).

I don't think there's anything fundamentally wrong using tags to indicate that a question/puzzle has *aspects* of that thing (i.e. your example is fine tagged with [sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sudoku)).

Comment: Hey, your gravatar changed!

Comment: @Deusovi - well that's weird... o_O

Comment: *Who are you and what have you done with the* real *Alconja?*

Comment: I don't know... I thought I was the real one... but now I'm not so sure... a coma maybe?

Comment: Looks like I've been hit by [whatever this issue is](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283643/why-is-my-profile-image-different)... I want my old one back :(

Comment: To me your gravatar looks the same as ever on the main site, but different (yellow) in chat.

Comment: @randal'thor - yeah, I "fixed" it, by grabbing a cached copy from archive.org and manually overriding the broken gravatar one.

Comment: Indeed. Besides, what would [A] [B] [variant] mean?

Comment: @RosieF I suppose that would mean a variant of both tags? Unless it is specified in the puzzle, which would defeat the purpose of the variant tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be necessary.

My guideline is this: I only make new tags if

- someone might want to ignore all posts of that type
- someone might want to only look at posts of that type

I can't imagine either of those cases occurring for [variant](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/variant).

Comment: There's a ***lot*** more issues than this surrounding tagging, including many possible criteria and even a lot of controversy on some sites. E.g. [here](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/2968) is a list of criteria which was used on Chem and SFF, but after more experience with it, SFF [decided](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9215/31394) that it was too unreliable. Shog has a [list of criteria](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/278659) which is simpler and better, but still has more to it than your one guideline here.

Comment: @rand: Yes, I realize that this is not *nearly* enough. I implicitly consider all of Shog's criteria as well - this is for whether a tag is *useful*, not whether a tag is *allowed*. (I find some of Shog's criteria trivially obvious - e.g. "on topic for the site" could probably go unstated.)